# How to iterate array in xslt

Tags: java, xslt-2.0

I am using XSLT version 2.0.

I am calling an external method which returns an array list object and storing the result into a variable in xslt. I want to iterate that variable and print the values but there is some issue in the transformation. Below is the code from xslt:

```
<xsl:variable name="listData">
      <xsl:value-of select="met:getData($Id)" />
</xsl:variable>
```

From the above expression I am getting below response from external method as an array in a variable listData:

```
[Test1, Test2, Test3]
```

When I am iterating the variable using below expression then values are not getting printed:

```
<xsl:for-each name="$listData">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:for-each>
```

but when I am printing directly using `<xsl:value-of select="$listData" />` then its working
I want to pring values one by one.

Could anyone please help me on how can I iterate the array in xslt.

Comment: Which XSLT 2 processor is that? Why do you XSLT expect to be able to process a Java array or ArrayList? Anyway, for a start, I would suggest to use `<xsl:variable name="listData" select="met:getData($Id)"/>`, that is all you can do on the XSLT side to bind the variable to the result from the function call, your current attempt makes the variable hold a tree fragment containing a text node with the string value of the result of your function call.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I am doing running some logic in java method that's why calling external method getData() and returning List<String> obj from there. That list I want to iterate here in xslt

Comment: Well, why do you expect an XSLT processor to be able to process a Java `List<String>`? And which XSLT processor is that? Does its documentation show how Java types are handled on the XSLT/XPath side?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Because I have some logic which needs to be processed and XSLT can't do that so I am calling an external method (Java method) and returning it back to xslt in form of array so that xslt can easily iterate over array elements. In XSLT it is printing whole array correctly but facing issue while iterating only.

Comment: Your are avoiding answering the crucial questions as to which XSLT 2 processor you use and whether/how its documentations suggests that a Java `List<String>` is represented on the XSLT/XPath side. I think, for Saxon PE or EE you might get them represented as an XPath sequence of string values so using `for-each` should work. But all that is very processor and perhaps edition/version dependent so it is crucial to know which XSLT processor and version you use.

Answer (score 0):

To give you an example on how it can easily work out if you know the XSLT processor (like Saxon Java PE or EE does) represents a `List<String>` in Java, using reflexive extension functions, as a sequence of strings to XSLT/XPath/XQuery, there you can easily process such a sequence so

```java
Processor processor = new Processor(true);

XsltCompiler xsltCompiler = processor.newXsltCompiler();

String xslt = "<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' version='3.0' expand-text='yes'
    xmlns:ExampleListCreator='java:com.example.saxon.ExampleListCreator' exclude-result-prefixes='#all'>
    <xsl:template match='/' name='xsl:initial-template'>
        <result>
            <xsl:for-each select='ExampleListCreator:returnExampleList()'>
                <item>{.}</item>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>";

XsltExecutable xsltExecutable = xsltCompiler.compile(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xslt)));

Xslt30Transformer transformer = xsltExecutable.load30();

transformer.callTemplate(null, processor.newSerializer(System.out));
```

outputs e.g. `<result><item>a</item><item>b</item><item>c</item></result>` with the Java function doing e.g.

```
public class ExampleListCreator {
    public static List<String> returnExampleList()  {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("a");
        list.add("b");
        list.add("c");
        return list;
    }
}
```

but whether and how that works is entirely up to the used XSLT processor.

Comment: Thanks Martin for your suggestion. Actually I have resolved my issue by changing the return type of external method from List to String. Now I am returning the String with comma separated elements to xslt and that string I am iterating in XSLT using tokenize() method. I am able to achieve the desired output from that.